# Why i'm getting NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created this method:

```
private string GetDirectoryName(string baseString, string baseName, int startAt)
{
            int i = startAt;

            while (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(baseString, baseName + i.ToString("D6")+"_"+DateTime.Now)))
            {
                i++;
            }
            return Path.Combine(baseString, baseName + i.ToString("D6") + "_" + DateTime.Now);
}
```

I added the `DateTime.Now` in the original the method was like this:

```
private string GetDirectoryName(string baseString, string baseName, int startAt)
{
            int i = startAt;

            while (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(baseString, baseName + i.ToString("D6"))))
            {
                i++;
            }

            return Path.Combine(baseString, baseName + i.ToString("D6"));
}
```

Then I'm creating the directory if needed:

```
string eventDir = GetDirectoryName(AnimatedGifDirectory, "Rain event ", 1);

if (!Directory.Exists(eventDir))
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(eventDir);
}
```

Before using the `DateTime.Now` it was working fine but after adding the `DateTime.Now` I'm getting the exception.

This is example for a directory that give the exception for example `eventDir` contain:

```
C:\test\Rain event 000001_10/26/2014 8:09:12 AM
```

The directory name the method created is this part:

```
Rain event 000001_10/26/2014 8:09:12 AM
```

Maybe the spaces after the 2014 to 8 and 12 to AM make the problem? Maybe the directory name should be something like:

```
Rain event 000001_10/26/2014_8:09:12_AM ?
```

What I want to do is that instead only create directories like Rain event 000001 and Rain event 000002 and Rain event 000003 something that will give each event and id since it's an EVENT.

So maybe to add somehow the date and time in any way. Something like that. So the directories will still be Rain event 000001 but with some date and time id after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `DateTime` results in illegal characters for a directory name, as an alternative you can use `DateTime.Now.ToFileTime()` which is a number representation of the current time (not necessarily unique if you do this concurrently or in a loop).

Answer (score 4):

It's the `:` character, it is an illegal path character in Windows OS. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx).

You can also call [`Path.GetInvalidPathChars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars(v=vs.110).aspx) method to find out if a char is invalid in path string.

Answer (score 1):

Per the MSDN documentation for `Directory.CreateDirectory`, a NotSupportedException is thrown if the directory name contains a colon that is not part of the drive label. When you include the `DateTime` you include a colon in the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

```
\ / : * ? " < > |
```

All of the above are invalid in a file name.